# merge repeating list items and change css accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Imagine I have array like this

```
myarray = ["apple","apple","apple","potato","apple",];
```

```js
myarray = ["apple","apple","apple","potato","apple",];
           
             function listCreate (data) {
       var output='<ul>';
       $.each(data,function(key,val){
     
        output+='<li">';
        output+='<h4 >'+ val +'</h4>';
        output+='</li>';
        
       });
       output+='</ul>';
       $('#mylist').html(output);
    }
   listCreate(myarray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mylist">
      </div>
```

I generate list with jQuery

And I need merge n repeating values and change li height n*50px

**Example**

```js
myarray = ["apple","apple","apple","potato","apple",];
```

```html
<ul>

<li style="background:#A6445E; height:150px;";>apple</li>
<li style="background:#FFD433; height:50px;">potato</li>
<li style="background:#A6445E; height:50px;">apple</li>

</ul>
```

**Example**

```
myarray =["potato","volvo","volvo","potato","apple",];
```

```html
<ul>

    <li style="background:#A7777E; height:50px;";>potato</li>
    <li style="background:#FFD433; height:100px;">volvo</li>
    <li style="background:#A4565E; height:50px;">potato</li>
    <li style="background:#A2125E; height:50px;">apple</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: You can remove duplicats with javascript like so - var names = ["potato","volvo","volvo","potato","apple",];
var uniqueNames = [];
$.each(names, function(i, el){
    if($.inArray(el, uniqueNames) === -1) uniqueNames.push(el);
}) , however I would recommend if you are getting it from a server (which you or someone has control), have the servers return method not send you duplicates.

Comment: Problem that i need repeating values but i want display it in one li tag and change it height accordingly

Comment: then I would recommend checking out .filter or .map with a certain return to suit your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make a new array using your original, but ignore duplicates that immediately follow:

```
myarray = ["apple", "apple", "apple", "potato", "apple", "apple"];

var temp = myarray[0];
var fixedMyArray = [temp]; 
var myArrayCounter = [];
var counter = 1;
for (var i = 1; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    if (temp != myarray[i]) {
        temp = myarray[i];
        fixedMyArray.push(temp);
        myArrayCounter.push(counter);
        counter = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
myArrayCounter.push(counter);

function listCreate(data,dataCounter) {
    var output = '<ul>';
    var temp = 50;
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {

        output += '<li style="background:#A7777E; height:' + temp*dataCounter[i] + 'px;">';
        output += '<h4 >' + data[i] + '</h4>';
        output += '</li>';

    }
    output += '</ul>';
    $('#mylist').html(output);



}
listCreate(fixedMyArray,myArrayCounter);
```

Then use `fixedMyArray` and `myArrayCounter` instead of `myarray` in your function.

`listCreate(fixedMyArray,myArrayCounter);`

Here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jpdjbcjt/1/

Comment: Please then explain what you want more clearly... I guess I don't understand, I thought you wanted to get rid of duplicates that are aligned next to each other?  Nevermind, I think I get it.  Let me make a quick change

Comment: i need do something like this 
if array value reapeat in the row n times i need change li height n times and display it only one time

Comment: Here I fixed it, see my JSFiddle it does exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are in need to create a counter to establish the correct class, not the correct style:
if you already are using jQuery you could take advantage.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mylist"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.small {
  background:#FFD433;
  height:50px;
}
.large {
  background:#A6445E;
  height:150px;
}
```

javascript:

```
var myarray = ["apple", "apple", "apple", "potato", "apple"], 
  listCreate = function  (data) {
  var output = $('<ul>'),
    listItem = $('<li>'),
    i,
    length = myarray.length - 1,
    counter = [];
  for(i = 0; i <= length; i += 1) {
    counter[data[i]] = counter[data[i]] + 1 | 1; 
    listItem
    .clone()
    .text(data[i])
    .addClass((counter[data[i]] === 1)? 'large': 'small')
    .appendTo(output);
  }
  $('#mylist').append(output);
};
listCreate(myarray);
```

jsbin.com:
http://jsbin.com/covakuseru/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/3xwtga6p/5/)

The function `function generate(array, colors)` takes two arguments `array`(`["potato", "potato", "volvo", "volvo", "potato", "apple", "apple", "banana"]`) and `colors`(`["#A7777E", "#FFD433", "#A4565E", "#A2125E", "#FFD433"]`), both should be arrays.

#### HTML:

```
<div id="myList"></div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
function generate(array, colors) {
    var newArray = [];
    var counts = {};
    var c = 0;
    var unique = '1';
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i + 1] != array[i] || i == (array.length - 1)) {
            newArray.push(array[i]);
            if (array[i] != array[i - 1]) {
                counts[unique] = 1;
            }
            unique++;
        } else {
            c = c === 0 ? 1 : c;
            counts[unique] = ++c;
            c--;
        }
    }
    $('#myList').append('<ul></ul>');
    for (i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        $('ul').append('<li class="' + i + '">' + newArray[i] + '</li>');
        $('.' + i).css({'height': 50 * counts[i + 1] + 'px', 'background-color': colors[i]});
    }
}

generate(["potato", "potato", "volvo", "volvo", "potato", "apple", "apple", "banana"], ["#A7777E", "#FFD433", "#A4565E", "#A2125E", "#FFD433"]);
```

```js
function generate(array, colors) {
    var newArray = [];
    var counts = {};
    var c = 0;
    var unique = '1';
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i + 1] != array[i] || i == (array.length - 1)) {
            newArray.push(array[i]);
            if (array[i] != array[i - 1]) {
                counts[unique] = 1;
            }
            unique++;
        } else {
            c = c === 0 ? 1 : c;
            counts[unique] = ++c;
            c--;
        }
    }
    console.log(counts);
    console.log(newArray);
    $('#myList').append('<ul></ul>');
    for (i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        
        $('ul').append('<li class="' + i + '">' + newArray[i] + '</li>');
        $('.' + i).css({'height': 50 * counts[i + 1] + 'px', 'background-color': colors[i]});
    }
}

generate(["potato", "potato", "volvo", "volvo", "potato", "apple", "apple", "banana"], ["#A7777E", "#FFD433", "#A4565E", "#A2125E", "#FFD433"]);

generate(["potato", "volvo", "volvo", "potato", "apple"], ["#A7777E", "#FFD433", "#A4565E", "#A2125E"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myList"></div>
```